# error message : "uncondensed distance matrix"

Tags: python

I have implemented hrp as described in the link below. I run with different inputs. The code produces reasonable results but I get the error message:

"**main**:75: ClusterWarning: scipy.cluster: The symmetric non-negative hollow observation matrix looks suspiciously like an uncondensed distance matrix"

Can anybody explain what it means?

link  for code:
https://github.com/lcamposgarrido/data-science_projects/blob/master/others/hierarchical_risk_parity/HRP.ipynb

Comment: You should open a request on github. This question is not for SO.

Comment: Did you look at https://github.com/widdowquinn/pyani/issues/73

Answer (score 1):

The [`scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) function accepts either a 1-D condensed distance matrix or a 2-D array of observation vectors. The warning just means your passing a 2-D matrix that looks like a redundant distance matrix (non-negative, symmetric, diagonal all zeros), but it is being treated as a 2-D observation matrix. If it is actually a distance matrix it should be converted to the condensed form before passing to `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage`. The [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) function may be used to convert between the two distance matrix forms.